# My java Program is creating 27 invalid errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I run these lines of my java code it gives me 27 errors that arn't actual errors

```
for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
  {
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
  System.out.println();
  }
```

aLeaderboard is an ArrayList with a custom class Leaderboard.It is 20 long, teamName is also an ArrayList which is 20 longs.

```
ArrayList<Leaderboard> aLeaderboard = new ArrayList<Leaderboard>();
```

it is producing these errors:

```
D:\>javac Project4.java
Project4.java:216: error: illegal start of type
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
  ^
Project4.java:216: error: ')' expected
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                 ^
Project4.java:216: error: illegal start of type
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                    ^
Project4.java:216: error: <identifier> expected
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                     ^
Project4.java:216: error: ';' expected
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                      ^
Project4.java:216: error: > expected
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                                      ^
Project4.java:216: error: <identifier> expected
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                                                     ^
Project4.java:216: error: illegal start of type
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                                                       ^
Project4.java:216: error: <identifier> expected
  for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
                                                        ^
Project4.java:217: error: ';' expected
  {
   ^
Project4.java:218: error: illegal start of type
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
        ^
Project4.java:218: error: ';' expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
            ^
Project4.java:218: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
             ^
Project4.java:218: error: illegal start of type
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                   ^
Project4.java:218: error: ')' expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                    ^
Project4.java:218: error: ';' expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                           ^
Project4.java:218: error: illegal start of type
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                              ^
Project4.java:218: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                               ^
Project4.java:218: error: ';' expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                ^
Project4.java:218: error: illegal start of type
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                   ^
Project4.java:218: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                        ^
Project4.java:218: error: ';' expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                          ^
Project4.java:218: error: illegal start of type
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                                    ^
Project4.java:218: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                                                ^
Project4.java:218: error: ';' expected
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
                                                                 ^
Project4.java:219: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.println();
                    ^
Project4.java:221: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
27 errors

D:\>
```

teamName contains 20 Strings that are all single Words.

Comment: Could you show us the code surrounding this block as well?

Comment: Have you correctly encased this code within a method in your class?

Comment: Are those lines written in a method? Or did you just put them in your class without a method?

Answer (score 0):

Is this code outside of a method?

Try replacing the current code with this:

```
public static test() {
for(int counter = 0;counter<teamName.size();counter++)
  {
  System.out.print((counter + 1) + "   " +  teamName.get(counter) + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getGamesPlayed() + "   " + (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeWins() + "   " +  (aLeaderboard.get(counter)).getHomeDraws() + "   ");
  System.out.println();
  }
}
```